# How can I make a before_filter function behave differently according to the action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3, permissions

I'm trying to make my authentication/permissions code a bit more succinct.

Currently I have this:

```
  def index
      require_role "normal" do
          @projects = Project.all
          respond_to do |format|
              format.html 
          end
      end
  end
```

where `require_role` handles checking permissions and redirecting to an error page if you try to do something you shouldn't.

I'd like to be able to just put something like this at the top of each controller:

```
require_role "admin", [:delete]
require_role "normal", [:edit, :new, :create]
require_role "guest", [:show, :index]
```

defined something like:

```
 def self.require_perm( role_name, actions )
    before_filter :require_perm_admin, :only => actions
 end
```

The only problem is that I have to hard-code the name of the method, `require_perm_admin`. That means, if I ever add new roles, I'd have to define a method for each one.

Is it possible to add dynamically named methods to a class? e.g. "check_role_admin", "check_role_guest" etc.

Otherwise, can I tell what action is about to be invoked from inside my `before_filter` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is the current action name, you can call `action_name` in the `before_filter`.  I'll leave the rest up to you if that's all you think you need :)

Comment: Perfect!
Where is this stuff documented? I seem to spend a huge amount of time just searching and never finding...

Comment: You make a good point: I don't know if it is.  It's a protected instance variable, so I don't think it's even in the API docs :(

Comment: Actually, it is documented here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something like

```
def self.require_perm( role_name, actions )
    before_filter "require_perm_#{role_name}".to_sym, :only => actions
end
```

Comment: That works to set up the filter, but you still need to define the function somehow. I don't see how to define the function dynamically, without know all the roles in advance.